# MVC2 : Passing string Array in ViewData, not able to use in Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Below is the controller action which returns Arrays in ViewData.

```
  ViewData["arrayTotalCertificateCount"] = arrayTotalCertificateCount;
        ViewData["_CertificateCategory"] = _CertificateCategory;
        ViewData["arrayCodeSeries"] = arrayCodeSeries;
        ViewData["arrayCodeCounts"] = arrayCodeCounts;

        return PartialView();
```

Now, in View, javascript, I am not able to access them.

Below is the code I have written in View Javascript.

```
 var arrayTotalCertificateCount = new Array();
    var i =0;

    for(var item in <%= ViewData["arrayTotalCertificateCount"]%>)
    {    
        arrayTotalCertificateCount[i] = item;
        i=i+1;
    }
```

It throws error like -

```
 for(var item in System.String[])
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
```

Can anyone please help me to convert this ViewData array in javascript array variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<% var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); %>
var arrayTotalCertificateCount = <%= serializer.Serialize(ViewData["arrayTotalCertificateCount"]) %>;
for(var item in arrayTotalCertificateCount )
{    
   arrayTotalCertificateCount[i] = item;
   i=i+1;
}
```

Comment: Satpal, thank you so much for quick reply. I tried your solution and I got rid of that error message. but Now I am getting below error. I think it is because of the space with numbers. I am not sure.              var arrayTotalCertificateCount =  "["5"," 5"," 1"]"
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
 Any idea, can I use item.Trim()?

Comment: Satpal, one more questions regarding this. I am getting CodeSeries as '70-158,70-169,70-181' from the controller and when I serialized it with var arrayCodeSeries = "<%= serializer.Serialize(ViewData["arrayCodeSeries"]) %>"; I am getting error message like -      var arrayCodeSeries = "["\u002770-158,70-169,70-181\u0027","\u002770-158,70-177,70-181\u0027","\u002770-680\u0027",null,null]";
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL   --------- Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: I tried with var arrayCodeSeries = '<%= serializer.Serialize(ViewData["arrayCodeSeries"]) %>'; and it worked fine.. Thanks